# Material applied to vertecies not changing color

Tags: materials

As shown in the pictures below the green material I changed to this blueish color, doesn't change in solid mode but it does in material preview and render preview mode. Did some reading regarding the issue but couldn't find anything I could fix it with.

Still bit of a newb in Blender and 3D, I do not understand many concepts but I hope someone can give me some pointers. Any tips and help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance guys!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an additional field further down in the material panel for the viewport display :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Colors in *Solid Mode* and real colors visible in *Material/Render* preview are independent.

[image]